# Unable to revert default shell from zsh to bash in macOS/Catalina: "chsh: no changes made"

Tags: macos, zsh, macos-catalina

I have a new `catalina` system and need compatibility with traditional `linux`. `bash` is a must.  Following various references I did

```
    chsh -s /bin/bash
```

But not too happy:

```
(base) 19:44:28// $chsh -s /bin/bash
Changing shell for steve.
Password for steve:
chsh: no changes made
```

Why did that not work?

Comment: 2 years later (_Monterey_  now..) i did a search on that error .. and landed on my own question.  I still don't know what to do about this

Comment: Not sure why this happens, but running `chsh -s /bin/zsh` enabled the bash shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why that approach didn't work, but I've never used that method myself.  Try the Mac-way of doing it.  Full details at https://www.howtogeek.com/444596/how-to-change-the-default-shell-to-bash-in-macos-catalina/, but basically go to System Preferences -> Accounts, unlock, ctrl-click on your acct name (Advanced Options), and change the shell!

Comment: Hi @jimtut, i have bash in these settings, yet after opening new Terminal I still see:
"The default interactive shell is now zsh. To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`. For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050."
Also my aliases I defined in ~/.bashrc are not working. In order to make them work I have to run "bash" command first. What it could be?

Comment: That output is just telling you that macOS has changed the default shell, it’s not telling you anything about your shell, except that it is probably not ZSH.  You’d have to type `echo $SHELL` or something to figure out what you’re running. Best guess is that you have something in another file (like .profile?) that is loading another shell after your launch a Terminal. You should really post a new question about this, more people will see it that way.

Comment: the line The default interactive shell is now zsh. To update your account to use zsh, please run chsh -s /bin/zsh. is so fucking confusing :|

Comment: This worked for me, but only after I restarted my computer.

Answer (score 2):

The `chsh` command actually works fine. It overrides the setting in System Preferences... Users & Groups... [unlock, right-click user] Advanced Options. You can check that it has changed the default shell with a command like

```
echo $SHELL
```

and you can see what shell you're actually in with

```
echo $0
```

If there is still a difference between the two, it's probably due to the settings of your terminal program. For example, in the default Terminal, in Preferences... General, there's a setting for *Shells open with* that could be the reason you're still being dropped in an unwanted shell.

Comment: That was my problem.  Although I had set my default login shell to a new version of bash, it was still using the old version at `/bin/bash` because terminal was set to open with Command which was set to `/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the "chsh: no changes made" message when trying to set the shell to `zsh` but my Terminal was still opening with `bash`. I checked System Preferences / Users & Groups / my-name / Advanced Options and the login shell was correctly at `/bin/zsh`.

The problem was **Terminal's preferences**, had "**Shell opens with**" set to `/bin/bash`. I changed this to "Default login shell" and it worked as expected.

[image: Terminal Preferences]

Answer (score 1):

Ignore the "no changes made." You just need to exit the shell program. You can do this by pressing Command q. When you relaunch iTerm you can confirm the change by typing echo $SHELL.